# my pdf reader does not show calligraphic letter produced by latex correctly?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf, calligraphy

I have used these two type styles, but they all show the same.

```
 $\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
 $\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
```

do I need to install some fonts for my reader?

Comment: Welcome, are you loading the `amsfonts` package? Or any other package supporting this? CAn you show a minimal working example? Do you get any errors or warnings?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `\mathcal` is a standard command `\mathscr` is not defined by default, so presumably you have used a package that has defined it to use the same font as `\mathcal` it will not be related to which pdf reader you use.

Comment: Unless a separate "math-script" font face has been set up, `\mathsct` defaults to `\mathcal`. That's why you're getting the outcome you're reporting. Please see the answer I just posted for a straightforward method for choosing calligraphic, script, blackboard-bold, and fraktur math alphabets.

Comment: Thanks all. I just removed unrelated code and rerun, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look into the capabilities of the [mathalfa](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalfa) package. It provides an easy interface for loading all kinds of math alphabets from various math font families.

The following example shows how one might employ the package to load script, calligraphic, fraktur, and blackboard-bold math alphabets. It is, at least in principle, possible to set up the math alphabets via separate commands; however, I believe it's much easier to get the job done using the machinery of the `mathalfa` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scr=rsfso,cal=zapfc,frak=euler,bb=ams]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

$\mathfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: the two fonts representing `\mathscr` and `\mathcal`*are* different, but not significantly.  the first shown (for `\mathcal` is much too like a usual "script".  only the "Q" and "S" are really distinct at a quick glance.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I chose the calligraphic and script fonts shown in the example above more or less randomly from a candidate list of math fonts. (Other choices would definitely generate much greater visual discrepancies.) FWIW, I'd say that in the screenshot shown above, D, E, H, Q, S, and V all look quite different. Are you suggesting I come up with different choices than `boondoxo` and `rsfso`?

Comment: `rsfso` is the "usual" script i see used by mathematicians, so i'd stick with that.  i'm (obviously) not familiar with `boondoxo`, but from its appearance, i'd characterize it as script, not calligraphic.  computer (or latin) modern calligraphic is the "usual" choice for that.  other candidates shown in the comprehensive symbols list are euler script or zapf chancery; both of those are free of curlicues, which are what distinguishes an "english script".  the most important characteristic of an alphabet used for math variables is that each letter be immediately recognizable in isolation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Many thanks for these observations. I've changed the 'mathcal' alphabet to Zapf Chancery; there's now a much better visual contrast to the 'mathscr' alphabet (rsfso).

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I especially agree with your view that "the most important characteristic of an alphabet used for math variables is that each letter be immediately recognizable in isolation." :-)

Comment: ams once published a (small) book in which the authors insisted on using five different lowercase script "p"s to mean different, but related, things.  (authors had to supply them; lowercase script is scarcer than hen's teeth for tex use.)  the differences were so subtle that i don't see how anyone could comprehend what was intended on first reading.  (proofreaders had trouble too.  authors did final check.)